# Обязательно ли делать sitemap для большого сайта?

Tags: seo, sitemap

есть большой форум.
Полезные ссылки выглядят следующим образом:
https://forum.woodtools.ru/index.php?topic=65548.0

Таких топиков порядка 43 тыс. плюс то что за точкой указывает на страницы топика, например
https://forum.woodtools.ru/index.php?topic=65548.25

Общее число полезных ссылок > 50тыс.

С помощью стандартных плагинов SMF (движок форума) создать sitemap мне не удалось.

Вопрос: обязательно ли делать sitemap или поисковый бот яндекс/google сам разберется ?

В robots.txt я запретил все технические ссылки.
ЧПУ ссылок нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При использовании карты сайта (sitemap.xml) роботам будет проще индексировать существующие/новые страницы сайта.
Будь у меня большой сайт (форум), я бы обязательно сделал карту сайта и индексировал бы сайт с помощью cron (к примеру, раз в неделю в 4 утра).

Comment: Не знаю какой мод у движка, но предположу, что путь к файлу запуска индексации сайта (генерации sitemap.xml) такой — site.ru/cron.php?cronmode=sitemap

И если у нас хост, к примеру, sweb, то команда для CRON будет выглядеть так /usr/bin/php5.5/home/a/account/public_html/cron.php?cronmode=sitemap

А уже непосредственно на хостинге (в панели управления планировщика CRON) выставляем время запуска.